# how to add a view over tapTargetView?

Tags: android

I need to add a button like `SKIP` over the `TapTargetView` for cancel the session of `TapTArgetView`.

I have already tried a button in the XML layout but it is not clicked due to the `TapTargetView`, so how do I add a custom view over a TapTargetView?

Answer (score 1):

no need of skip button use .cancelable(true);

Comment: yes,i have already add the same as you said , but i want to cancel this all on a particular button click . I want to do all cancel process on a particular button click.

Comment: now at any place click it is cancelling but
 I simply want to add a button at top right corner so by press the button this all should be cancel rather than tap on TapTargetView  .